# Android save bitmap to media without compress and set it in image view

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, compression

```
   //CROP INTENT
    private void doCropping
   {
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(selectedImageUri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 16);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 9);

    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    try {
        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(cropIntent, code);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

//CROP RESULT

 private void resultOnCropOkOfGallary(Intent data) {
    Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
    this.bitmap = extras2.getParcelable("data");
    if (this.bitmap != null) {
        //ivPicture is Imageview.
        ivPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

}
```

I get image after cropping perfect.But it makes image quality low.
I got blured image set on imageview. Please need solution.Thank you.

Comment: Shouldnt you use `selectedImageUri` instead?

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks, but selectedImageUri returns me full image after cropping. Without crop effect.

Comment: You are already fidling around with aspectX/Y. Some other values maybe? Cannot you better tell what you get? Resolutions compare please. Is it cropped or is it the normal bitmap when taking a picture? Please compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for some image cropping libraries.

1) https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

2) https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the link. I am using android-crop library for cropping. It's very simple and helpful. (Y)